# Separate Latitude and Longitude of googlemaps by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I use google map and want separate string `(46.43303011014231, -95.1344145834446)` that get by following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {

    //placeMarker(event.latLng); // this output is: (46.43303011014231, -95.1344145834446)

    var str = event.latLng;
    var ret = str.split(",");
    alert(ret[0]); // this don't work for me

});
```

I want it as:

```
Latitude = 46.43303011014231
Longitude = -95.1344145834446
```

How can they be extracted from `(46.43303011014231, -95.1344145834446)` by jquery?

Answer (score 8):

`event.latLng` is a `LatLng` object which you're converting to a string unnecessarily. Use [the object's native methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng):

```
var lat = event.latLng.lat(); 
var lng = event.latLng.lng();
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent

Comment: I have this error: 3Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lat' of undefined . see my full code: http://pastebin.com/zPHGR2Pj

Comment: `event.LatLng` should be `event.latLng` - with one lowercase L - my mistake (since corrected).